# adb: failed to install my_application-aligned.apk: Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_UNEXPECTED_EXCEPTION: Failed to parse AndroidManifest.xml]

Tags: java, android, android-studio

When I try to install my apk onto my Android Virtual Device in Android Studio with `adb install my_application-aligned.apk`, I get the following error: `Performing Streamed Install adb: failed to install my_application-aligned.apk: Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_UNEXPECTED_EXCEPTION: Failed to parse /data/app/vmdl530526663.tmp/base.apk: AndroidManifest.xml]`
Could this be because the apk is corrupted? I can provide my Android Manifest file if that would help. I generated the APK by following this tutorial: https://medium.com/@_sathishshan/decompile-and-recompile-android-apk-7d375e1bca83 . Following this tutorial, I first downloaded an XAPK file from the internet. Then, I decompiled the APK and added some additional files to the application. Next, I recompiled the APK, and generated a new APK file. This new APK file is `my_application-aligned.apk`. Thanks!

Comment: check **minSdkVersion**, it's maybe too big. or clear and rebuild project with androidstuidio.

Answer (score 1):

So this doesn't really answer how to get rid of the error, but I think this error is showing up because the original file that I downloaded from the internet was an **XAPK** file, not an **APK** file. I just tried to do this whole process again with an APK file downloaded from the internet (not an XAPK file), and the error did not appear. So it might have something to do with the original file that I decompiled being an XAPK.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall old app from device and re run this app to device again.

Comment: When I run ```adb uninstall my_application-aligned.apk```, I get the following error: ```Exception occurred while executing:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown package: my_application-aligned.apk```. So it's almost as if the ```adb install my_application-aligned.apk``` command never actually installed anything.

Comment: you can manualy unistall app from device

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: Actually, I think I tried to do that when I went into Settings -> Apps and Notifications on my Android Virtual Device, and the app was not listed with all the rest of the apps. So I don't think it ever got installed.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me by clearing the builds folder

```
./gradlew clean
```

or

```
Android Studio --> Build --> Clean
```